# NHiberate "No parameterless constructor" for mapping to StringType

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

Starting with an object mapping that was working perfectly fine for SqlLite, I tried to use the same code with Oracle, and found out that, by default, all of my string fields were mapped to `VARCHAR2(255)`. While that works out fine for most of the fields, it's way too small for one field.

I thought it would be a simple matter to make the field bigger. Hah!

I tried this:

```
            Property(prop => prop.BigField, map =>
            {
                map.Column("BIG_FIELD");
                map.Length(65535);
                map.Type<NHibernate.Type.StringType>();
            });
```

This produces this error:

> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not instantiate IType StringType: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

A few of my search results have told me that I should use `NHibernateUtil.String` instead of `NHibernate.Type.StringType`. But all that gets me is this:

[image]

What's really weird is that I get `String` as an autocompletion suggestion, but then I can't use it. I tried to see if the code would compile in spite of the red squiggly line, but it doesn't. I also tried `StringClob`, with the same results.

Any helpful suggestions? All I want to do is make this string bigger than 255 characters. I didn't expect something so simple to fight back so hard.

Answer (score 1):

To use types provided inside `NHibernateUtil` class use overload taking persistent type as **parameter** and not inside generic definition:

```
Property(prop => prop.Property, map =>
{
    map.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
    map.Length(length);
});
```

In you case it seems it makes sense to map it to `NHibernateUtil.StringClob`:

```
Property(prop => prop.BigField, map =>
{
    map.Column("BigField");
    map.Type(NHibernateUtil.StringClob);
});
```

And there is nothing weird that code is not compiling inside generic for  `map.Type<NHibernateUtil.String>();` - generic definition expects type (like `string`) and not instance of type (like `"value"`) which you are trying to supply

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer (so I'm still curious why I had the above problems), but this workaround is good for now:

```
            Property(prop => prop.BigField, map =>
            {
                map.Column("BigField");
                map.Length(65535);
            });
```

The schema shows that the field becomes a CLOB object, and that's just fine for me for this application.